# can gmail filters apply superstars (ie red bang etc) or stil only yellow star?

Tags: gmail-filters

this was asked in 2011, when it wasn't possible. Has anything been improved on this front in the last 10 years? It'd be very handy as i use different stars to sort emails into multiple inboxes, but currently have to apply the different stars manually...
Thanks

Comment: Welcome to Web Applications SE. There are no changes regarding superstars. Even Google Apps Script and the Gmail API can't be used to apply them.